How do I make displaystyle math (\[\]. \begin{equation}, etc.) vertical spacing equivalent to \centering \(\)? (Also having issues with unicode-math)
Essentially what I want is for environments such as align, equation, \[\], etc. to have the same amount of space as
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Fat

\centering \(Fat\)

\end{document}

Doing so with \[Fat\] instead of \centering \(Fat\) obviously makes more vertical space but I want it to be possible so that I can just add something to the preamble that doesn't make me have to add something every time I want to do what I want to do mid-document
Would greatly appreciate any help with my problem.
Edit: Both of the answers worked, but when I attempted to use the unicode-math (must use package for me) along with the code, and it sort of reset the effect of the code for the vertical space reduction. Can someone help with this? how do I fix this?

You can add the settings to the font size changing commands, so even if \normalsize is executed (which LaTeX does in a few places), it won't reset the skips to the default value.
THe setting has also to be done at begin document.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\makezeroskip}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
}
\AddToHook{cmd/normalsize/after}{\makezeroskip}
\AddToHook{cmd/small/after}{\makezeroskip}
\AddToHook{cmd/footnotesize/after}{\makezeroskip}
\AtBeginDocument{\makezeroskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-4]
\[
a+b=c
\]
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\bigskip

\footnotesize

\lipsum*[1][1-4]
\[
a+b=c
\]
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\bigskip

\normalsize

\lipsum*[1][1-4]
\[
a+b=c
\]
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}



If you really must you can set the vertical display space to 0pt, but you need to delay it as \normalsize executed at \begin{document} will set it back (unless you redefine \normalsize)

\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}%
}
\showoutput
\begin{document}

Fat1

{\centering \(Fat\)\par}

Fat2
\[Fat\]


Fat3

\[Fat\]

\end{document}

The third case is really in error, there should never be a blank line in the source before display math, but it more or less works out OK once everything is set to 0.

This seems to conflict with the unicode-math package when paried with this code, why could this be? does a remedy exist? the package is a must for my projects.

@FerriusUndermine the code works with or without \usepackage{unicode-math} no remedy is needed.
